# C - usage of extern qualifier

Tags: c, extern

I have following three files. In the header file, I declare a global variable and tried to access it other files using `extern`. But I got the linker errors.

Header1.h

```
  #ifndef HEADER1_H
  #define HEADER1_H

  #include<stdio.h>

  int g = 10;
  void test();

  #endif
```

test.c

```
  #include "header1.h"

  extern int g;

  void test()
  {
       printf("from print function g=%d\n", g);
  }
```

main.c

```
  #include "header1.h"

  extern int g;

  int main()
  {
     printf("Hello World g=%d\n", g);
     test();
     getchar();
     return 0;
  }
```

Linker error:

```
  LNK2005   "int g" (?g@@3HA) already defined in main.obj   
  LNK1169   one or more multiply defined symbols found
```

My understanding about `extern` is that a variable can be defined only once but can be declared multiple times. I think I follow it this way - I defined the global variable g in the header file and tried to access it in the .c files.

Could you please correct my understanding? What actually causes the linker error here? I did not define `g` multiple times.

Comment: "a variable can be defined only once" is true, yet as a global `int g;` (not used here) is a _tentative definition_.  Research _tentative definition_ for details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get a multiple definition error because you put the definition in the header file.  Because both source files include the header file, that results in `g` being defined in both places, hence the error.

You want to put the declaration in the header file and the definition in **one** source file:

In header1.h:

```
extern int g;
```

In test.c:

```
int g = 10;
```

And nothing in main.c.

Comment: It is worth reminding that a `#include` statement, for most intents and purposes, is identically equivalent to copy/pasting that file's content into the file doing the including.